# jQuery: Scroll to

Tags: jquery, scroll

Can somebody help me, I want to use in jQuery something like "ScrollTo".

When I click something ,  --- >  scroll to some div

Like in HTML  with anchors

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) jquery plug-in.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a quick way to do it, this should work:

```
  $('html').animate({scrollTop: $('#myelement').offset().top});
```

See [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more options.

Comment: You need to change 'html' to 'body' to make it work. Nice trick, though!